# Линковка статической библиотеки в cmake (linux)

Tags: cmake

Если в директории лежит две библиотеки  динамическая и статическая с одинаковым именем то cmake линкует динамическую, есть способ указать cmake что бы он подключал статическую?

Comment: Укажите библиотеку вместе с расширением .a

Comment: А есть еще варианты?
Нужную мне библиотеку нужно линковать в разных конфигурациях на разных платформах и будет неудобно составлять имя библиотеки потому что для каждой конфигурации оно разное.

Comment: например для библиотеки mylib
libmylib.a
libmylibd.a
libmylib.so
libmylibd.so
mylib.lib
mylibd.lib
mylibmt.lib
mylibmtd.lib
mylibmd.lib
mylibmdd.lib

Comment: Самый простой способ, запускать сборку из sh скрипта, в нем можно определить платформу и передать CMake скрипту нужные параметры (имя либы, например). Но можно обойтись и без sh скрипта, просто проверив наличие нужных либ в файловой системе: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067401/cmake-check-that-a-local-file-exists.

Comment: Но, если делать все по науке, то можно попробовать так https://htcondor-wiki.cs.wisc.edu/index.cgi/fileview?f=build/cmake/FindLinuxPlatform.cmake&v=4592599fecc08e5588c4244e2b0ceb7d32363a56 , т.е. определить платформу и в зависимости от этого формировать имя либ(ы) в переменной.